# How can I get my Angular app to allow refresh in production - URL Rewrite?

Tags: angular, url-rewriting

Locally I can refresh a page and it will load (i.e., `localhost:4200/customers`) but in production - hosted on myasp.net IIS website - when I go `www.mysite.com/customers` I get a 404, but If I go:

1. `www.mysite.com`
2. Click the "Customers" button
3. I am redirected to `www.mysite.com/customers` and the page display properly

however if I refresh, I get a 404!

I did some research and see that I can:

1. Update the web.config with

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but there is no web.config

1. `HashLocationStrategy`,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [
  // Define your application routes here
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

but I got this from ChatGPT so I'm not so sure. Wanted to see what
you say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added the web.config at the root, now it works!!!

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finally ChatGPT gave me the write technical answer! Woo hoo!

Comment: really you use HashLocationStrategy????? this makes that you have an ugly `#` in your url :(